# Why does the continuity of Lyapunov function matter?

Tags: control-theory, lyapunov-functions

Why does the continuity of Lyapunov function matter?

Is there any example where discontinuity of $V$ is problematic even if it does not change the sign but it is strictly decreasing and yet not stable?

---

From wikipedia:

A Lyapunov function for an autonomous dynamical system

\begin{cases}g:\mathbb {R} ^{n}\to \mathbb {R} ^{n}\\{\dot {y}}=g(y)\end{cases}

an equilibrium point at $y=0$ is a scalar function

$$V: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$$

that is continuous, has continuous derivatives, is locally positive-definite, and for which $-\nabla V.g$ is also locally positive definite. The condition that $-\nabla V.g$ is locally positive definite is sometimes stated as $\nabla V.g$ is locally negative definite.

Comment: You might find examples that though the function is decreasing the switching can push the state to higher levels thanks to the dynamics of $g$, I vaguely remember switching system literature has some examples but I can't recall any from the top of my head. Note that Lyapunov function does not stabilize the system, it just points to the dissipation direction of a point in the state space.

Comment: @percusse, thanks a lot. However, without any example it is hard to judge.

Comment: The proof of the Lyapunov theorem proceeds by utilizing level sets of $V$. Without at least piecewise continuity, these level sets may not exist.

Comment: @ITA, sorry but not convinced. Any example?

Comment: Read the proof.